# Removing and adding a view in prism prevent it from activating it

Tags: wpf, prism, region

I have a WPF application which uses prism regionmanager. I should add a control in run time to a registered view .I removed the view from region and changed it and then added it into the region again . But , When i want to activate the new added view the application hangs .

```
    var view = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<CheckListView>();
    var views = 
   _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainRegion].Views.ToList();
    var active = _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainRegion].ActiveViews;
    CheckListView view2 = views.SingleOrDefault(v => v.GetType().Name == 
   "CheckListView") as CheckListView;

    _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainRegion].Deactivate(view2);
    _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainRegion].Remove(view2);    
      //    _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainRegion].RemoveAll();   

        view.ScheduleGroup.Children.Clear();

       if(SelectedType.ToString().Equals("newview"))
        {

            var control = 
           (ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<BuildingCheckListView>());    
             view.ScheduleGroup.Children.Add(control);
            view.chkCombo.SelectedItem = CheckListTypeName.OfficialBuilding;

        }

        _regionManager.AddToRegion(RegionNames.MainRegion, view);
       _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainRegion].Activate(view);
```

Comment: You should debug your application and show us what code causes your app to *hang*, or what *exception* do you observe. By the way, I see a lot of issues in your current code: 1) avoid using a `ServiceLocator` (it's an anti-pattern); 2) a call to `View.ToList()` without using the result; 3) `v.GetType().Name == "CheckListView"` is probably meant to be `v.GetType() == typeof(CheckListView)`.

Comment: The code hangs on   _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainRegion].Activate(view);